# Users are unable to login to SQL Server dev database

Tags: sql-server, backup, refresh

I have refreshed the development database manually from production database backup. After refreshing the database, the Dev team is unable to login and access to that database. Please let me know your thoughts to troubleshoot systematically to resolve this issue.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Most likely, you had specific users in your dev database, that now have been wiped out since you restored a prod backup, and I assume in your prod database, your dev team doesn't have any user accounts ....

Comment: See http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Copying%20logins%20and%20passwords%20from%20one%20SQL%20Server%20to%20another.aspx  backup/restore doesn't restore users fully

Answer (score 0):

Unable to login coz:

```
1. users are don't have a permission to access your database.
2. Check Sql service if running on you system Services.
3. if on server or another pc, Check server ip if you'd be able to ping it.(Network Connectivity).
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First thing First.
Do Check the **Server Name** and **Authentication**
If you have updated your DB in your local machine. Then the Server Name must be like:

> **SystemName\SQLEXPRESS**

Do Also check out the Login with the permission

Answer (score 0):

After refreshing the database, all the data level user access will be lost. Only SysAdmin users will be able to access the database. For any database level users need to be granted access again.